# Domain Wide Google Service Account Impersonation alternate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-iam

I am working on a system where I am to access individual user drives in a domain using domain wide service account. My issue is to find an alternatives where service account can access individual gdrive files without impersonating.

What all I have till now:

1. I have service account configured with domain wide delegation.
2. Relevant scope and role is been configured for service account.

Use case: Access individual drive files using service account within same domain.
Current Understanding: All I know is that service account impersonates as a user whose drive it wants to access.

Question: Is there anyway that my system can manage individual gdrive files without impersonating?

Comment: Each user must share a folder to the service account email address. Configure "Share with people and groups".

Comment: Thanks John, Let me try this and see if it fits in my use case. thanks for your help.